# .os file unrecognized while building glibc

Tags: glibc

While building glibc, I get this error.

```
*glibc/build/elf/dl-allobjs.os: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status*
```

What is an .os file and what binutil do I need to install to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> What is an .os file

It's just an object file, intended to be linked into a shared library. UNIX linkers for the most part don't care about file extension, you can call file `foo.o`, `foo.oS`, or just about anything else, it would still work.

> what binutil do I need to install to fix this?

It's unlikely that your problem has anything to do with binutils. It is more likely that the file got corrupted somehow.

What does `file glibc/build/elf/dl-allobjs.os` report? Are you cross-compiling? Does the problem reproduce if you reconfigure and rebuild in a different directory?